# Lync \ S4B UCMA Video Queue or IVR

Tags: video, skype, lync, ucma

I'm looking to build an application that will accept inbound IM & Voice\Video Calls using an Application Endpoint and when the Application Endpoint Answers, start sending a video to the user.

Looking at the UCMA examples I can see that this is trivial for Audio\IM using either the AudioVideoCall Class or the InstantMessagingCall Class. However as of UCMA 5.0 I still can't see any way of being able to Send video from the Application to a user. Which is odd considering the Class has Video in the Name.

Does anyone have experience with sending a video from an Application Endpoint to an Inbound Caller?

From what I've researched the only way would be to extend the AudioVideo Class but I haven't seen anything so far as to how to do that or the first idea on what would be involved?

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

As of UCMA 5 there is still no supported way to create a video call in the same way you can with audio.  However one approach that may work would be to host the video in the CWE on the desktop client.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I sadly figured that video still wasn't supported. 

I had thought of using the CWE but we also want to support the Skype desktop and mobile clients for some of the external (to the Company) inbound connections and I can't really see anywhere that the CWE is available for that.

My only real option at this stage is to conference all Inbounds with another client using a virtual webcam and Back To Back the call in and out. Just seems overly complicated given how easy Audio and IM is.